# SQL How to get all the week from now two months to the past

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query (SQL Server) that groups my info by end weekdate. This is working fine. The problem is that if for some reason I don't have any data for a week then that week won't be generated and my chart that I need to plot will be wrong.

This is a sample data I get from my query:

[image]

This is my query:

```
select 
permittype,
count(0) as total,
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,  DATEADD(d, 7 - DATEPART(DW, ei.createddate),ei.createddate))) as WeekEnding
from employee_incident ei
where ei.incidentcode = 'P'
and ei.isactive = 1
and ei.createddate >= DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
group by
permittype,
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,  DATEADD(d, 7 - DATEPART(DW, ei.createddate),ei.createddate)))
order by 
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,  DATEADD(d, 7 - DATEPART(DW, ei.createddate),ei.createddate))) desc
```

> How can I make that if week '2015-11-14' has no data I get 0 as total value? Right now if that week has no value I just don't get the row.

Comment: You will need to create a table of weeks and `LEFT JOIN` it to your table.

Answer (score 0):

This will require a Weeks table and either a LEFT JOIN or a FULL OUTER JOIN depending on where you start the query. In the weeks table you can create one record per week of the year. You can add all kinds of data about that week but we can start with the following.

```
CREATE TABLE weeks (
    week_number TINYINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    start_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    end_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
);
```

In the below example I use a FULL OUTER JOIN as I have left the query taking directly from the employee_incident table, however if you changed it to start from the weeks table you could LEFT JOIN onto the employee_incident table. We use COALESCE to give default 0 value of permit type when no data exists in employee_incident and COALESCE again to preferentially take the data from employee_incident when it has data.

The CROSS APPLY is to avoid having to repeat the code for getting the week ending. We write it once and then can use its alias after that.

```
SELECT COALESCE(permittype, 0) as permittype,
    count(0) as total,
    COALESCE(EndOfWeek, week.end_date) as WeekEnding
from employee_incident ei
cross apply ( 
    select DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0,  DATEADD(d, 7 - DATEPART(DW, ei.createddate),ei.createddate))) as EndOfWeek
) _
full outer join weeks on ei.WeekEnding = weeks.end_date
where (ei.incidentcode = 'P'
    and ei.isactive = 1
    and ei.createddate >= DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()))
or weeks.end_date is null
GROUP BY COALESCE(permittype, 0),
        COALESCE(EndOfWeek, week.end_date)
ORDER BY WeekEnding DESC
```

I haven't created these tables and executed it so let me know if there is any error in the SQL.